# Java File.exists and other File operations returning wrong results for an existing File (network, macosx)

Tags: java, macos, networking, filesystems

The filesystem AirportHDD is mounted (AFP) from the beginning and the file exists when I start this little program.
I tried to figure out the whole day why the following is not working, but couldnt find any solution:

```
public static void main(String[] arguments)
{
    while(1==1)
    {
        File f=new File(
                "/Volumes/AirportHDD/test/lock.csv");
        System.out.println(f.exists());
        AmySystem.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

the output is:
true, true, ...

as soon as I remove the file from a different computer (AirportHDD is a mounted harddisk over network) then the output keeps saying:
true, true, ...
when I open the finder and goto this directory the output changes to: false, false, ...

when the file is added again (via another pc) the output is still:
false, false, ...

but if you open the finder again and click on the directory and finder shows the existing file, the output changes suddenly to: false, true, true, true, ...

NOTE:

- also all other file operations like opening for read are failing as long as java 'thinks' the file is not there
- if the program itself is creating and deleting the files then problem is not occurring
- just found out while testing that with samba sharing everything is ok, but with AFP it just wont work

is there a way to tell java to do the same thing as finder, like a refresh, or do not try to cache, whatever?

Comment: I guess it gets `mounted` when you open it via finder. Being available and being mounted are different.

Comment: @rocketboy: That doesn't match the reported symptoms. Clearly if it was reporting the file existed (the initial `true` `true` `true`), the file system was mounted.

Comment: the file system is mounted from the beginning, corrected start situation

Comment: What type of network mount is this? This does sound like a caching issue, and it's quite common on NFS.

Comment: its AFP, yes it seams that only finder can do something like a refresh and other OS calls still get wrong results

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is the network file system AFP. With the use of SAMBA everything works like expected.

Maybe the OS returns the wrong file info in OSX with the use of AFP in these scenarios.

Comment: see solution above for the current SAMBA implementation on OS Mavericks

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html). Oracle was also kind enough to provide a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

Because the longevity of these links aren't guaranteed, I'll edit in an example code in a couple of minutes. I just wanted to let you know I think I found something in case you want to start looking at it for yourself.

**UPDATE**
Following the linked tutorial, I came up with code like this. I'm not sure it'll work (don't have time to test it), but it might be enough to get you started. The `WatchService` also has a `take()` method that will wait for events, which means you could potentially assume the file's existence (or lack thereof) based on the last output you gave. That will really depend on what this program will be interacting with.

If this works, good. If not, maybe we can figure out how to fix it based on whatever errors you're getting. Or maybe someone else will come along and give a better version of this code (or better option altogether) if they're more acquainted with this than I am.

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    Path path = Paths.get("/Volumes/AirportHDD/test/lock.csv");
    WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    WatchKey key = null;
    try {
        key = path.register(watcher,
                       ENTRY_CREATE,
                       ENTRY_DELETE);
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.println(x);
    }

    while(true) {//I tend to favor this infinite loop, but that's just preference.
        key = watcher.poll();
        if(key != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                if (kind == OVERFLOW || kind == ENTRY_DELETE) {
                    System.out.println(false);
                }
                else if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    System.out.println(true);
                }
            }//for(all events)
        }//if(file event occured)
        else {
            File f=new File(path);
            System.out.println(f.exists());
        }//else(no file event occured)

        AmySystem.sleep(100);
    }//while(true)
}//main() method
```

Comment: sounds great, but i like to have static methods that tells me if a file exists. if i get this watch service right i need to register for changes which could be difficult to implement in the current design

Comment: I won't pretend to know your design, but I understand that some solutions just aren't compatible. I'm not sure if this will be work with your system design, but I guess that'll be your call. If it turns out it won't work, I'm sure someone else will be able to find a different solution.

Comment: thx a lot i will try to implement it, i just found out while testing that with samba sharing everything is ok, but with AFP it just wont work

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JUnit test that shows the problem 
The problem still happens using Samba on OSX Mavericks. A possible reason
is explaned by the statement in:
     http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/11/apple-shifts-from-afp-file-sharing-to-smb2-in-os-x-109-mavericks

***It aggressively caches file and folder properties and uses opportunistic locking to enable better caching of data.***

Please find below a checkFile that will actually attempt to read a few bytes and forcing a true file access to avoid the caching misbehaviour ...

**JUnit test:**

```
/**
 * test file exists function on Network drive
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Test
public void testFileExistsOnNetworkDrive() throws Exception {
    String testFileName="/Volumes/bitplan/tmp/testFileExists.txt";
    File testFile=new File(testFileName);
    testFile.delete();
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        Thread.sleep(50);
        System.out.println(""+i+":"+OCRJob.checkExists(testFile));
        switch (i) {
        case 3:
            // FileUtils.writeStringToFile(testFile, "here we go");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/ssh phobos /usr/bin/touch "+testFileName);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**checkExists source code:**

```
/**
 * check if the given file exists
 * @param f
 * @return true if file exists
 */
public static boolean checkExists(File f)  {
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
        if (is.read(buffer) != buffer.length) { 
            // do something 
        }
        is.close();
        return true;
    } catch (java.io.IOException fnfe) {

    }
    return false;
}
```